# ArrayList Data not properly transferring to Array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

When I log out the sectionList there are 20 items; for some reason, all but the last item is being entered into the section Array.  Can someone see whats wrong here?

UPDATE:  I posted the entire class in question; it's relatively short.  It is from an Android app.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> implements
        SectionIndexer {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ItemObject[] objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_row_layout, objects);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int size = objects.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            ItemObject it = objects[i];
            String name = it.name;
            String s = name.substring(0, 1);
            s = s.toUpperCase();

            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s)) {
                alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
            }
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

        sections = sectionList.toArray(new String[sectionList.size()]);


    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @KickingLettuce you can use `ArrayList.toArray`. Also, if you want ordered keys, use a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++) {
        sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sections.length - 1; i++) {
        sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);
    }
```

Why are you copying the array twice here? Also, why not use an `Iterator`? Actually, what you should **really** use is [`ArrayList.toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) to convert to `String[]`, e.g.

```
sections = sectionList.toArray(new String[sectionList.size()]);
```

Additionally, you can have your keys sorted by using a `TreeMap` as opposed to a `HashMap`, merely by doing [`TreeMap.keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet%28%29)...

> The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order.

Comment: I apologize, I had the wrong code in that for loop.  I have updated up top and added more.

Comment: @KickingLettuce why are you looping twice to copy the array?

Comment: @KickingLettuce where are you logging to determine it's one short?

Comment: Thank you, that did what I needed! I also am using the more efficient 'toArray' as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: @KickingLettuce what about using `TreeMap`?

Comment: Since it's simplifying code, I will incorporate it.  I just needed to get it working first without crashs.  I will do refinements later.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason behind that is the condition in the for loop `i < sections.length - 1;`.  You are probably logging `sections[i]` only in the for loop.

Comment: You must remove the `nextElement` definition to prevent an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I have updated code; that part you saw in the last for loop was incorrectly left in.

Comment: @veer: Correct changed my answer.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: But the last for loop you just added doesn't make sense at all.